# android: Navbar color issues - doens't appear on other activities than MainActivity

Tags: android

I'v choose nav. drawer activity in the beginning (App has an actionbar) and didn't changed anything, I just added the following to v21/styles.xml:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

When I run it on my phone, the navigation bar color which I needed is showing on mainactivity, but when i go to any of the other activities it is showing black. please help me and let me know if i need to show any other code from project.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.spiritual.manohar.blogs">

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/picsart"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DebateStuff" />
    <activity android:name=".SB" />
    <activity android:name=".UPS" />
    <activity android:name=".PV" />
    <activity android:name=".PU" />
    <activity android:name=".OIS" />
    <activity android:name=".VS" />
    <activity android:name=".DisplayActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".About"></activity>
  </application>

  </manifest>
```

Comment: check in your manifest, is the style applied on other `activites` also?

Comment: @AbdulKawee please check (sorry, I'm new to Android prog.), i've added it in the post.

Comment: you need to apply `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` this theme to all the other activites, if you want same result

Comment: your welcome buddy, if it helped you, then please mark correct my answer below, happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options make one global theme or assign a theme to every activity

You can assign all Activity like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.spiritual.manohar.blogs">

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/picsart"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DebateStuff" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".SB" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".UPS" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".PV" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".PU" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".OIS" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".VS" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".DisplayActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".About" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
  </application>

  </manifest>
```

or you can assign **@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar** global the in manifest file or remove another theme in activities

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/picsart"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: Got the desired results. Thank you so much :) I'm learning so much from Stackoverflow's members.

Answer (score 0):

If you want same result on all other activities , then you have to add theme to other activities also, or one quick way around is to apply it to whole application.

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/picsart"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```